# SQL: Finding exact string within another string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find an exact string within a list of other strings on an SQL Server. The first string could partially be part of another string.  For example, looking for 123 within 123 and 01230 only returning the first row as its an exact match. Not returning the string 01230.  The original string could be of varying length, so I could be searching for 123, or I could be search for 1230. Further example below:

Say, I have a column of strings like:

_VB12345.VB84556
_VB1234.VB84556
_VB12345.VB8455
_VB8455.VB1234

what query would I write to find:

VB1234 - returning the 2nd and 4th value
VB8455 - returning the 3rd and 4th value

I cannot just write:

```
select *
from table
where reference like '%VB1234%'
```

As this would return all 4 rows.

I also cannot write:

```
select *
from table
where reference like '%VB1234.%'
```

As this would return the second row only.
I'm not sure how to include special characters as the string terminator.

I hope this makes enough sense to people

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: I don't really understand the logic here. Please explain why it's invalid for the first search term to return the fourth row while it's perfectly valid for the second search term to return the third row. Also, it would be nice to have some more sample data that includes edge cases and is formmated as DDL+DML statements so that we can copy it directly to a test environment and play with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your case you should be able to do

```
where reference + "." like "%VB1234.%"
```

for a better answer, in the more general case you probably need to look into regular expressions.

Comment: Shame SQL Server doesn't have regular expressions.

Comment: you can do regex with UDFs, if the DBA lets you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2007/february/sql-server-regular-expressions-for-efficient-sql-querying

Comment: Yeah, bad for performance though.

Comment: thanks @Z.D. this will be best in the current situation. Cheers